# How to calculate Scheduled Snasphot cost in GCP using google platform pricing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I can calculate it manually using the documentation on the image pricing page but wish to be able to calculate it fast using the pricing calculator

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)